# Is there a way to theme the notifications in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, notification

I'm kinda bored of how they look and the fact that there's only 3 themes to choose from is even worse, so I was wondering if there is a way to theme the notification bubbles of XFCE?.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Theming the xfce notifications

The themes of the notification bubble defined by a specially formatted file called `gtkrc` found within the folder structure `/usr/share/themes/[theme name]/xfce-notify-4.0`

All system-wide themes must follow the above naming convention.

For user-specific notification bubbles, the same `[theme name]/xfce-notify-4.0/gtkrc` file & folder structure can be created in your home folder `~/.themes`

Lets create a copy of an existing notification bubble theme to work with - our new theme is going to be called `playtime`:

```
mkdir -p ~/.themes/playtime/xfce-notify-4.0
cp /usr/share/themes/Greybird/xfce-notify-4.0/gtkrc ~/.themes/playtime/xfce-notify-4.0/
```

Now launch the notification manager in system settings:

[image]

You'll see our new `playtime` theme.

#### customisation

Now lets have some fun with customizing this theme.

Open the `gtkrc` file for `playtime`

```
leafpad ~/.themes/playtime/xfce-notify-4.0/gtkrc
```

When customising the theme - change to another notification theme and back to `playtime` for the change to take effect.

#### changing the font

The bit in this file we are interested in to customise the text is this section:

```
style "greybird-notify-text"
{
    fg[NORMAL] = "#ffffff"
    GtkWidget::link-color = "#a7a7a7"
}
```

We can customise the font by adding `font_name = "Serif 18"` to this (between the `{ ... }`:

[image]

So where to we get the font name - easiest place is actually the Font Window in the Appearance window:

[image]

Just add the text descriptions together as shown - for example `Serif Italic 10`

#### changing the font colour

We can change the font colour by modifying the `RBG` format number i.e. `ff0000` is Red, `00ff00` is Blue and `0000ff` Green - other colours are mixtures of these.

Thus - `fg[NORMAL] = "#ff0000"` gives us this:

[image]

#### changing the background colour

The bit in this file we are interested in to customise the background colour is this section:

```
style "greybird-notify-window"
{
    XfceNotifyWindow::summary-bold = 1
    bg[NORMAL] = "#111" 
    XfceNotifyWindow::border-color = "#ffffff"
    XfceNotifyWindow::border-radius = 10.0
    XfceNotifyWindow::border-width = 3.0
}
```

The `bg[NORMAL]` value is again in RBG format - e.g. `#00ff00` is green:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use Image files as background?

Comment: @UriHerrera - I've look at this - the widget control appears to be limited to fonts/font sizes/font colours and background colours - no image control.  I've tried the usual CSS syntax for images but this results in the whole notification theme using the plain "Default" theme :(

Comment: I see, what about the XML syntax that gtk 2 themes used? that doesn't work either?.

Comment: looking at notify-osd source code I dont see any evidence of image handling capabilities of the notification bubble system. Sorry about that.